# Can't log in with requests

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, debian, cgi, python-requests

I'm using the following simple Python script to log in to a cgi page:

```
import requests
url = 'someSite'
data = {'username': '<userName>', 'password': '<password>'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False)
```

But then I get the following error message:

[image]

Also, I have this message from Firefox at the bottom when I inspect the HTML:

> This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use
>   certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions
>   stronger than SHA-1

So, what might be the problem?

**Update:**
info: Python 2.7.9

Comment: Your question should contain the error message as a text instead of an image.

Comment: What version of Python do you use? The error looks like there is a problem with SNI support, but Python should support SNI since 2.7.9.

Comment: Kidnly check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by using `mechanize` instead of `requests`. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import mechanize

loginURL = '<url>'

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

browser.open(loginURL)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['username'] = '<username>'
browser.form['password'] = '<password>'
login = browser.submit()
```